# How to mock or test an async cb function with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

say I have this:

```
componentDidMount() {
 window.Something.windowFunction(EVENT_HANDLER, this.myFunc)
}

myFunc() {
  // test that this was called
}
```

how can I mock the window object to make sure that I get inside the `myFunc`

I've done this

```
const mockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation((eventHandler, eventCallback) => {
    return eventCallback()
})

global.Something = {
    windowFunction: mockFn('event-handler', () => jest.fn()),
}
```

but it's never calling `myFunc`